# wso2 project loading time after UI changes

Tags: wso2-api-manager

1. org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.8.1.jar
2. org.wso2.am.styles_4.2.0.jar

based on documentation the file is extracted and again converted to jar file.

JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /var/www/html/wso_new/backup/wso2_project

Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2023-09-30 18:23:53,701]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}

- Configurations Changed in :repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml
  [2023-09-30 18:23:53,701]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/resources/security/listenerprofiles.xml
  [2023-09-30 18:23:53,701]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory /var/www/html/wso_new/backup/wso2_project
  after file changes above line is loading not running the project.

Comment: What are the changes you have done ?